# Error while running Java in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jdk

I'm getting an invalid error while creating project name of Java in Eclipse.
I hope you suggest me any solution to it.

Error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f0be18f4a29, pid=3098, tid=139689460168448
#
# JRE version: 6.0_27-b27
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.12.6
# Distribution: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, package 6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.2
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgail.so+0x36a29]  gail_misc_get_type+0xa89
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Comment: Update your OpenJDK. May be Eclipse would be needed 1.7 libraries & as you have 1.6 installed.